# Update master branch using another branch which doesn't have all the files master contains?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-merge

I am new to `git` and this is my situation:

I have two branches:

1. `master` - contains `README.md`, `tests/all/*.py`, `package/*.py`
2. `unit-testing` - contains `tests/units/*.py`, `package/*.py`

The `unit-testing` branch **doesn't** contain `README.md` and `tests/all/*.py` which `master` does contain. Moreover, the content in `unit-testing`'s `package/*.py` is newer.

I want the newer content of `unit-testing`'s `package/*.py` to overwrite the older content of `master`'s `package/*.py`. This can be done by me. But I also want the files in `master`, such as README.md, which are not in `unit-testing` to remain as they are in `master`.

But when I try to `merge` `unit-testing` into `master`, I see that the files not in `unit-testing` get deleted from `master`. I can't merge `master` into `unit-testing` as `unit-testing` contains newer content.

More specifically, I run the following command:

`$ git checkout master
$ git merge unit-testing`

Git removes `README.md` and `tests/all/*.py` from `master`.

Comment: Unless you added the removal of `tests/all/*.py` in `unit-testing`, this should not be happening.

Comment: I had not forked `unit-testing` out of `master`. I had created a new branch `unit-testing` and copied the required files. I am a beginner and didn't know about forking.

Comment: Forked? Who mentioned forking? I'm talking about the `unit-testing` branch. Why did you copy files in the new branch? Weren't the files already there?

Comment: I had created some files in `master` later on (after the `unit-testing` branch was created). Sorry, I about mentioning fork; I had not understood you properly.

Comment: You confused me there... can you update your question with a _simplified_ git tree of your commits? I'd like to understand what you did.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you created "**unit-testing**" branch from "**master**" branch. If yes you can merge master branch into unit-testing branch. Some times this will give you conflicts. resolve the conflicts and merge again "unit-testing" into "master" branch. Its better you get a backup of project before doing this.

```
git checkout unit-testing
git merge master
```

Now if you got conflicts resolve them,

```
git commit
git checkout master
git merge unit-testing
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `unit-testing`, or more specifically the commit it points at, once had `README.md` and `tests/all/*.py` in its history but they were then removed. When you merge `unit-testing`, these deletions are also introduced into `master` so `README.md` and `tests/all/*.py` are removed from `master`.

If you'd like to keep the deleted files in `master`, here are two solutions if you intend to merge `unit-testing` to `master` but keep some files untouched.

The first:

```
git checkout master
git merge unit-testing --squash
git checkout HEAD -- README.md tests/all/*.py
git commit
```

This way, the changes of `unit-testing` except `README.md` and `tests/all/*.py` are introduced to `master`. But when you look at their history graph, `unit-testing` and `master` are still diverged as if they have not been merged.

The second:

```
git checkout master
git merge unit-testing
git checkout ORIG_HEAD -- README.md tests/all/*.py
git commit
```

This way, all the changes of `unit-testing` are introduced to master, so at first `README.md` and `tests/all/*.py` are removed. But then they are brought back by `git checkout ORIG_HEAD -- README.md tests/all/*.py`.

The two methods almost do the same thing to the files, but create different histories. You could see the differences by `git log --oneline --graph --decorate unit-testing master` in the two cases.

If you'd like to go back where they were after your tries, run `git reflog master` and `git reflog unit-testing` to find out which commit they were on. Suppose `master` was on `abc111`, you can make it back by:

```
git checkout master
git reset abc111 --hard
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer you've accepted may have led you to a solution, and the other answer factually describes your situation and *also* could lead to a solution; but both o them are treating symptoms.

Branches aren't intended for separating test code from production code (or more generally one part of a project from another part).  If you create a branch on which you delete a sizable chunk of your project, you should reconsider your workflow.

What are you trying to address by having the test code on its own branch?  Have you looked at more typical solutions to whatever problem you're trying to solve?

How do you intend to keep the test code in sync with the main project code, as each of them change?  How will you know *which* commit on the test branch should test which commit on the main branch?  "The 5th commit tests the 5th commit"?  Will limit your use of git until it eventually fails.  "Documentation based on tags or commit ID's or some such"?  Not a practical discipline to keep up.

If you fix the underlying problem of using branches in a way that runs against their grain, you won't have the stated problem.